# reading text file and writing to two dimensional array in perl?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';
use List::Util qw( sum );

my $filename =  'data1.txt';

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
}

my $filename2 = 'data2.txt';

open(my $fh2, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename2)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename2' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh2>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
}

my @last = ();

my %grades = (
    Ahmet => {
        quiz1 => 97,
        quiz2 => 67,
        quiz3 => 93,
    },
    Su => {
        quiz1  => 88,
        quiz2  => 82,
        quiz3  => 99,
    });

my %sum;

for my $name (keys %grades){
    $sum{$name} = sum(values %{ $grades{$name} });
}

for my $name (sort { $sum{$a} <=> $sum{$b} } keys %sum){
    push @last, "$name: $sum{$name}\n";
}

my %grades2 = (
    Bugra => {
        quiz1 => 33,
        quiz2 => 41,
        quiz3 => 59,
    },
    Lale => {
        quiz1 => 79,
        quiz2 => 31,
        quiz3 => 62,
    },
);

my %sum2;
for my $name (keys %grades2){
    $sum2{$name} = sum(values %{ $grades2{$name} });
}

for my $name (sort { $sum2{$a} <=> $sum2{$b} } keys %sum2){
    push @last, "$name: $sum2{$name}\n";
}

my @last1 = sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b) } @last;

print @last1;
```

This is my code. I want to take values from a text file something like ( marry 10 65 23) and write to a two dimensional array. I managed array separately end of the read text file it has to be seen like `grade1` and `grade2` for `data1.txt` and `data2.txt`. I can pull the values but I couldn't write to two dimensional array. Also result is correct.

Comment: Ahmet: 257
Bugra: 133
Lale: 172
Su: 269
My output is correct but it takes values from grade1 and grade2 I want to take from text files.

Comment: `my @foo = ();` is redundant: `my @foo;` already creates an empty array.

Comment: Show sample input/output data, and please ask a more specific question than "how do I do this?".

Comment: I'm not asking that .I wanted to show that I can take file values from .txt my question is how can I push or pop text values into two dimensional array like grade1 or grade2.Because I want to hash them after.

Comment: `%grade1`/`%grade` are hashes, not arrays. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [two dimensional hash data output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983542/two-dimensional-hash-data-output/47983892#47983892). Some portions of the code seem quite familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question as ***How do I populate the hashes `%grade1` and `%grade2` from the files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt`?***

I also assume that your files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` have the following structure (whitespace separated):

```
marry 10 65 23
john 20 30 40
```

I suggest to write a function that takes the filename as paramater and returns a reference to a populated hash:

```
sub read_grades_from_file
{
    my $filename = shift;
    my $result   = {};

    open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename )
      or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!\n";
    while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
        next unless $row =~ /\S/;    # skip empty lines
        my ( $name, $quiz1, $quiz2, $quiz3 ) = split( ' ', $row );
        $result->{$name} = {
            quiz1 => $quiz1,
            quiz2 => $quiz2,
            quiz3 => $quiz3,
        };
    }
    close($fh);
    return $result;
}
```

The function is used as follows:

```
my $result = read_grades_from_file('data1.txt');    # returns hashref
my %grade1 = %{$result};                            # dereference $result to make it a hash

$result = read_grades_from_file('data2.txt');
my %grade2 = %{$result};
```

The result of `read_grades_from_file` is a *reference* to a hash so it has to be *de-referenced* and then assigned to `%grade`. Thus the two steps.

Comment: that's work thanks.But I want to put text variables in an array.I'm doing that but It takes first row of the text as an array input and I don't want that  It takes like that @array("ahmet 36 45 76","chris 34 95 20")

Comment: @FatihTEKE I don't know what you mean. You have the ***hashes*** `%grade1` and `%grade2` and now talk about ***arrays***. Because you do not show what you really want it is not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the data structures you are using are overly complex. You probably only need a single `%grades` hash, for example.

The following will take data from space- or tab-separated records from both two input files - ignoring comments or empty lines.

```
my %grades;
while (1) {
  my $row1 = <$data1>;
  my $row2 = <$data2>;
  last unless (defined $row1 or defined $row2);
  chomp ($row1, $row2);
  if (defined $row1 and $row1 !~ /(^#|^$)/) {
    my ($name, @quizzes) = split /[ \t]/, $row1, 4;
    $grades{$name}{'grades1'} = sum(@quizzes);
  }
  if (defined $row2 and $row1 !~ /(^#|^$)/) {
    my ($name, @quizzes) = split /[ \t]/, $row2, 4;
    $grades{$name}{'grades2'} = sum(@quizzes);
  }
}
```

To print to STDOUT, you could try the following.

```
print "Name\tMarks 1\tMarks 2", $/;

for (keys %grades) {
  my $name = $grades{$_};
  print $_, "\t", $name->{grades1} || '?', "\t", $name->{grades2} || '?', "\t", $/;
}
```

With data1.txt as

```
# Grades
Bugra 33 41 59
Mary 10 65 23
Lale 79 31 62
```

and data2.txt as

```
# Grades 2
Bugra 49 32 57
Lale 79 31 62
Peter 21 34 42
```

the output is shown below.

```
Name    Marks 1 Marks 2
Peter   ?       97
Lale    172     172
Bugra   133     138
Mary    98      ?
```

(A '?' indicates that no record exists for the specified student in one of the two input files.)